# Nested divs dislocate parent divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to add some nested spans to my divs but they keep dislocating the divs that contain them.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gL9mxjL/

As you can see, if you hover the mouse over the one of the white div a child div will appear and dislocate its parent. I can't seem to find the reason for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".port-list").on("mouseenter", ".port-thumbnail", function() {
    $(this).find(".port-title").slideToggle();
  })

  $(".port-list").on("mouseleave", ".port-thumbnail", function() {
    $(this).find(".port-title").slideToggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.portfolio {
  height: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../static/images/portfolio-background.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.portfolio-title {
  top: 100px;
}
.port {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.port-thumbnail {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}
.port-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px;
}
.port-area {
  width: 800px;
}
.port-title {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  bottom: -130px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio container-fluid" id="portfolio">
  <center>
    <div class="intro-title portfolio-title">
      <strong>My Portfolio.</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="port-area">
      <ul class="port-list">
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="port">
          <div class="port-thumbnail">
            <div class="port-title">wow</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: how you want to show ?

Comment: Better describe what you like to implement, please

Comment: @AlexanderElgin  I want to show a title for each thumbnail whenever I mouse over it. I can already do that, but whenever the title divs show up the thumbnail divs get dislocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just eliminate the javascript all together and get a smoother effect with more control.

```css
.portfolio {
    height: 800px;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("../static/images/portfolio-background.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.portfolio-title {
    top: 100px;
}
.port {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.port-thumbnail {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    background: #fff;   
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.port-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}

.port-area {
    width: 800px;
}

.port-title {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    bottom: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s linear;
    transition: bottom 0.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1s linear;
    padding: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.port-thumbnail:hover .port-title {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gL9mxjL/8/)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
.portfolio {
    height: 800px;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("../static/images/portfolio-background.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.portfolio-title {
    top: 100px;
}
.port {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.port-thumbnail {
    position:relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px;
    background: #fff;   
}

.port-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
}

.port-area {
    width: 800px;
}

.port-title {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gL9mxjL/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gL9mxjL/5/)

```
            .portfolio {
                height: 800px;
                background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url("../static/images/portfolio-background.jpg");
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-size: cover;
            }

            .portfolio-title {
                top: 100px;
            }
            .port {
                    position: relative;
                top: 100px;
                /* display: inline-block; */
                /* position: absolute; */
                    float: left;
            }
            .port-thumbnail {
                    height: 150px;
                width: 200px;
                margin: 30px;
                background: #fff;
                /* position: relative; */
            }

            .port-list {
                    list-style-type: none;
                /* display: inline; */
                padding: 0px;
            }

            .port-area {
                width: 800px;
            }

            .port-title {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                color: white;
                bottom: -130px;
                position: relative;
                display: none;
            }
```